# Word Puzzle: Tellurium Yahweh

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

Take the phrase "Tellurium Yahweh" and work with word associations until an answer emerges.

(This is a weird puzzle.  Probably will not be solved and will frustrate many.)

The answer is a declarative statement. An acceptable answer could have the form: "There IS [blank] [blank] [blank] [blank] !" where [blank] represents a word. Other correct declarative statements are possible as well.

Hint:

> Final answer does not sound like initial words at all.

Hint:

> What is the short hand for elements?

Comment: What are we supposed to do?

Comment: I think we should act frustrated.

Comment: Hmm, work with word associations until an answer arises.

Comment: @Jiminion, can you add that in the question? Otherwise this will be closed. There are no instructions and no question

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil,  Well, Myst had no instructions either.... oh well.

Comment: "Tell her I am away."

Comment: HINT:  An acceptable answer could have the form:  "There IS <blank> <blank> <blank> <blank> !"  where <blank> represents a word.  Other correct declarative statements are possible as well.

Comment: @JuanTomas  That is a very good try!  (This probably will be solved...)

Comment: Hint: Final answer does not sound like initial words at all.

Comment: Hint:  What is the short hand for elements?

Comment: While you've edited this puzzle to make it a bit clearer, "work with word associations until a declarative statement emerges" is still extremely vague, and could lead to any number of possible answers, so I'm not voting to re-open.

Comment: Hint:  The word associations lead to a single word, which then leads to a (somewhat obvious) declarative statement.

Answer (score 5):

The Answer:

> Tellurium = Te,  Yahweh = The God known as "I am";
>  Te I am  = Teiam;
>   "There IS an I in team!"

Answer (score 4):

All credit to Juan Tomas if this is right:

> Tell her I'm on my way.

Comment: Nice try Xeno/Juan.

Comment: Just a remark, that you have two other options besides posting an answer with the note *all credits to X*: 1. Suggest to X in a comment to post their guess as an answer; or 2. post it yourself, but as a community answer.

Comment: @Matsmath, this is fine because he's not posted exactly what Juan said, he's taken inspiration from it. No need to comment or post as a com wiki

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, it's my mistake, I overlooked that this answer is different.